# Foundry-Workshop - Charts with multiple layers

Tags: charts, palantir-foundry, foundry-workshop

I would like to know what are the settings capabilities on workshop charts when implementing multiple layers.

Here is an example of a chart with 2 layers (3 objects):
[image]

Among the global settings options, I would like to know:

- how to have only one legend per group, instead of one per layer?
- how to manage colors? Is it possible to change default?
- is there any way to display dotted lines for example?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

- how to have only one legend per group, instead of one per layer?

Currently all the legend "flattens" all the series across all the Plot Layers and there isn't any way to change the grouping. If you really wanted to, you could use a couple metric widgets in List or Tag mode and build your own legend alongside the chart, assuming you'd made overrides for all the potential series and series segments (see below).

[image]

- how to manage colors? Is it possible to change default?

Yes, you can change the color for each series on the chart. If the series has no "Segement By" config, then you can choose the color directly. If you choose to segment by some other property, then you need to add a Segment Display Override for each segment value that you want to change.

- is there any way to display dotted lines for example?

You can change the style from solid to dashed in the same place that you can change the color

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work, unless I missed something: this `Segment Display Override` settings is related, as it's named, to overriding conditions, witch means when a segment overrides another one. As far as I understood, it's mainly used with bar charts.
Btw is it the same story in Quiver?